# What is the difference between "der Gruss" und die "Begrüssung"?

Tags: difference

Ich habe Folgendes gelesen:

**Der Gruss**
Es grüsst:

- der Mann die Frau
- die jüngere Person die ältere
- die rangniedrigere Person die ranghöhere.

**Die Begrüssung**
Es begrüsst:

- die Frau den Mann (ausser der Mann ist wesentlich älter)
- die ältere Person die jüngere Person
- die ranghöhere Person die rangniedrigere.

Comment: Where did you get this from?

Answer (score 1):

Gruß = You meet e.g. on the street (walking by) and just say "hello".

Begrüßung = You come to an invitation or any other "official" event or a meeting and someone welcomes you.

Answer (score 1):

*Gruß* are the few words uttered as greeting, such as "Guten Tag".

*Begrüßung* tends to mean the procedure, and during workshops, conferences, offical meetings etc. the first agenda point is typically called likes this, summarizing the greeting to the audience, introduction of the speaker, welcomes to official representatives and similar stuff.

I can't confirm the very peculiar use of the words your citation, in fact I would even contradict it.